# NSFetchedResultsController returning objects with another context

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In order to get information from an entity I have called Entry for my table view cells, i have this code:

```
Entry *entry = [self.appDelegate.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"timeline entry contexts: %@ and %@", [[AppDelegate applicationDelegate] managedObjectContext], [entry managedObjectContext]);
```

The two managedObjectContexts return as being different. Here is my fetched results controller:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entry" inManagedObjectContext:[AppDelegate applicationDelegate].managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[AppDelegate applicationDelegate].managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And here's my MOC:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

        [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
            [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
        }];
        _managedObjectContext = moc;

        _managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = [[NSMergePolicy alloc]
                                            initWithMergeType:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

I'm unsure why it's returning a different MOC. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you set `_managedObjectContext = nil` anywhere in your program? Then `[[AppDelegate applicationDelegate] managedObjectContext]` would return a newly created MOC, while `self.appDelegate.fetchedResultsController` might still use the old MOC.

Comment: Two things; try setting the cacheName property of the FRC to nil instead of @"Root". Secondly, don't set a merge policy on your MOC. Should help you on your way. Got a feeling the merge policy is your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing the cache Root before executing the request declaring the root

```
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[AppDelegate applicationDelegate].managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:@"Root"];
```

I came across something similar lately and that fixed the problem